# Cartan formalism calculation

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, curvature

Just to test out the Cartan formalism, I decided to apply it to the sphere. So, it admits a metric,

$$\mathrm{d}s^2 = \mathrm{d}r^2 + r^2 \sin^2 \phi \mathrm{d}\theta^2 + r^2 \mathrm{d}\phi^2$$

from which I may define an orthonormal basis,

$$\omega^{r} = \mathrm{d}r, \, \, \, \ \omega^{\theta} = r\sin \phi \mathrm{d}\theta, \, \, \, \,  \omega^{\phi} = r \mathrm{d}\phi.$$

I applied Cartan's first equation, i.e.

$$\mathrm{d}\omega^a + \Gamma^a_b \wedge \omega^b = 0$$

to determine the connections $\Gamma^{a}_b$; I obtained

$$\Gamma^{\theta}_\theta = -\frac{1}{r}\omega^r - \frac{1}{r} \cot \phi \, \omega^{\phi} \, \, \, \, , \, \, \, \, \Gamma^{\phi}_\phi = -\frac{1}{r} \omega^r$$

in terms of the orthonormal basis. Cartan's second equation states,

$$R^a_b = \mathrm{d}\Gamma^a_b + \Gamma^a_c \wedge \Gamma^c_b$$

but all exterior derivatives of the connections vanish. In addition, I think the second term vanishes as well, implying the curvature 2-form $R^a_b = 0$. However, this is not the correct result? By the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem, this would imply the Euler characteristic $\chi = 0,$ which implies the genus $g=1$. But a sphere has genus $g=0$. Can someone see where I went wrong in the calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did is *not* on a sphere. You performed all the calculations in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is *flat*, only in spherical coordinates!

Try instead dropping the $dr$, since you don't need it. Stay *on* the sphere. 
You get a metric:
$$
ds^2 = r^2 sin^2\theta\, d\phi^2 + r^2\,d\theta^2.
$$

With only two dimensions, calculations get much, much simpler, try! (For example, 2-forms are 1-dimensional...)

To simplify calculations even more, you can even fix $r=1$ (don't do this is if you want to find the relation between $r$ and the curvature).

Comment: I feel so embarrassed... Thank you!

Comment: I just tried the computation with the metric you supplied (with a correction, you had two $d\phi^2$ terms). The only non-zero connection is $\Gamma^{\phi}_\phi$, which again means I'm getting $R=0$...

Comment: Ah nevermind, got the right answer.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: $d\omega^{\phi} = \cot\theta \omega^{\theta} \wedge \omega^{\phi}$ would give me $R=0$ eventually, but if I exchange the wedge product, picking up a minus sign, I get $d\omega^{\phi} = -\cot\theta \omega^{\phi} \wedge \omega^{\theta}$, which somehow conspires to make $\Gamma^{\phi}_{\theta}$ non-zero, which gives me a single non-zero curvature component, namely $R^{\phi}_\theta = -\sin \theta d\theta \wedge d \phi$. I think this whole method of 'reading off the components' has a slight margin of error; are there other ways to compute the Ricci form without Cartan's equations?

Comment: I was just checking the Perimeter Institute lectures on gravitational physics from Prof. Ruth Gregory; when she applies the formalism, she always swaps the wedge product in the derivatives of the basis. I'm not sure why.

Comment: The Cartan method is by far the most convenient, both computationally and conceptually. Working with differential forms instead of general tensors saves you from calculating a lot of null and/or equal components...Yup, the (only) drawback is that you have to be very careful with the signs and the ordering!

Comment: By the way, do you know how I can convert $R^{a}_{b}$ back into the coordinate basis? (The reason I ask is for GR, to then get from the Einstein tensor to the stress-energy tensor.)

Comment: You have to use the tetrads: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrad_formalism